# Is there any method that I can open an alert dialog with list of choices in flutter based on an if condition?

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, dialog

So basically I have a countdown timer for a minute and when the minute finishes I want an alert dialog to pop on the screen for the user e.g:

```
if (isCompleted) {
      //open the dialog widget here
}
```

I can't find solutions for that. I'm only finding solutions that opens the dialog on button press.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this in a project of mine to display an info dialog when opening the app for the first time:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                                       //etc
                                )
```

You can probably wrap your widgets in a `FutureBuilder` (so you have access to `context`) with your countdown as the `future` argument, and, when the countdown is over, you can call `showDialog` from there.